# Email not receiving after order

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2.3,  VPS hosting. I want to ask the question about this website https://www.marketplace.jawadditaksal.org

when the order comes, the customer receives the email very late after two hours,
and admin even not receive the email after order. Even I set the SMTP settings. What other setting required for this.

and also how to change the display name of the email when the customer receives the email.

please look at the screenshot of admin panel:
https://ibb.co/zVGtFMG
https://ibb.co/THzZn7P
https://ibb.co/3yjXpLC

Comment: Please check cron and smtp log

Comment: @AmitBera SMTP is correctly set but yes cron settings are pending, Could you please help me how to set cron setting, as it is and in my dreamhost panel these are the field what i need to fill in that : https://ibb.co/58cZ4rc

Comment: @AmitBera waiting for your reply